# Jetstream, laravel 8 email verification does not work

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I have a problem with email verification.
I have uncommented `Features::emailVerification(),`also I have implemented MustVerifyEmail in my User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
```

and I have 3 routes in my web.php

```
Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
    return view('auth.verify-email');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();

    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');

Route::post('/email/verification-notification', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('status', 'verification-link-sent');
})->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.send');
```

but still I don't get email when I register, can someone help please.

Comment: When you're using Jetstream, you don't have to configure those routes yourself, so you can remove that part. But I'm also having this issue - on first registration, the notification isn't sent, but if you manually hit the button to send the notification, it will send.

Comment: My app has been around since Laravel 5.x and somewhere along the line while upgrading, I forgot to add the new event listener in core. In EventServiceProvider.php:

```
protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Maybe that will help someone adding Jetstream/Fortify to an existing app.